# How to create an Ext.data.Model from a generic object?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I want to create a real `Ext.data.Model` record that could be loaded later into a form from values held in an object.

Is this possible ?

The issue is that I have a grid which holds actual `Ext.data.Model` objects, that I load into a form, but some logic in my form renders the form again, clearing all form values and loading the record once again.

Thing is that the user will lose all changes when this logic is performed. So I'm thinking of using the form's `getValues()` which returns an object, recreate an `Ext.data.Model` and then load it again in the form.

Any ideas if this is possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: `getValues` doesn't return an array. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-getValues

Comment: @EvanTrimboli You're right, it returns an object. I'll see if it's loadable into a form as `loadRecord` expects an `Ext.data.Model`

Comment: @EvanTrimboli `loadRecord` returns an error when loading the result of `getValues`

Comment: Right, because loadRecord expects you to pass a record. You need to read the docs about what types are accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
var record = Ext.create('ModelName');
record.data = form.getValues();
```

This creates a record loadable into a form.